# SEO friendly URL of opencart not working inside Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes, opencart

I have a site which is mainly based on Code igniter.Inside that I have a store setup using opencart.Everything working fine until I try to user opencart seo friendly urls.

Once done that,it shows codeigniter 404 view.

How can I bypass CI routes when url is xyz.com/store

My Htaccess file is here :

```
# Customized error messages.
ErrorDocument 404 index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
  #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]      
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Post your htaccess. You need to add an exception to remove the /store directory from your htaccess rules.

Comment: @Jeemusu I have added the htaccess file.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely caused in your `.htaccess` file. The default Codeigniter `.htaccess` file is set up to route all traffic to your public directories index.php. To prevent this you will need to set up a `RewriteCond` to exclude any directories you want to keep outside of codeigniter.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(store[^/]*)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks but still the same. :(

Comment: weird, i tested both locally and they worked. Might be a bigger problem.

Comment: Done.One mistake I made that, my htaccess file in store folder was disabled.Thanks